# Hive and Mysql Error

Tags: mysql, hive

I set Hive hadoop on CentOS of VMware of Mac. And I set Mysql on Mac. When I use 'schematool -dbType mysql -initSchema' command I got error blow. 
[image]

Then I checked my hive-site.xml

```
    <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
    <value>Root@123</value>
    <description>password to use against metastore database</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
    <value>root</value>
    <description>Username to use against metastore database</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
    <value>jdbc:mysql://192.168.168.1:3306/hive6</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
    <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
    <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
  </property>
```

On the Mysql server, I did the flush privileges below:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO  'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'Root@123'; 
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Still got same Error..
```

Comment: Edit /usr/local/etc/my.cnf and change the bind-address from 127.0.0.1 to *.

Then run brew services restart mysql

Comment: May be mysql is not listening on 192.168.168.1:3306. you need to try Qinghe's solution and update question

Comment: solved as I comment above -.-